# How to pass the dynamic data into the wpmail() in cron job wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-task, wp-mail

`enter code here`i wants to pass contact form entries into the wpmail() in cron job. but the dynamic data not pass insite the wpmail function .pls help me to resolve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to read the database table for contact form entries and pass the count into mail functtion . and sent mail using wpcron in wordpress please help me to pass count into mail body